# Installing new packages do not work, always getting errors

Tags: r, installation, package, warnings, cran

As an Example:

```
 install.packages("mosaic")
Installing package into ‘\\abc/User/username/Dokumente/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 2424832 != reported length 3316431
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/sp_1.4-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1871414 bytes (1.8 MB)
downloaded 544 KB

package 'png' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages : 
error 1 in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages : 
 cannot open compressed file 'raster/DESCRIPTION', probable reason ' No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

Tried also for example:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

similar errors and warnings + additional:

```
Warnung in file.create(to[okay])
  kann Datei '\abc/User/username/Dokumente/R/win-library/3.5/ggplot2/CITATION' nicht erzeugen. Grund 'No such file or directory'

Warnung in file(con, "w")
  kann Datei '\\abc/User/username/Dokumente/R/win-library/3.5/ggplot2/doc/index.html' nicht öffnen: No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "w") : kann Verbindung nicht öffnen
ERROR: installing vignettes failed
* removing '\\abc/User/username/Dokumente/R/win-library/3.5/ggplot2'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
```

I checked as well (saw this in another discussion):

```
 getOption("repos")
                       CRAN 
"https://cran.rstudio.com/" 
attr(,"RStudio")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I can't be sure but the issue is not the repository but you library location/path. Try creating a library in a different place than your documents folder.

Comment: unfortunately, this won't work, because of no admin rights to change the library location/path. I already have some packages installed some time ago, which worked.

Comment: Is `\abc` a network drive? You either have an issue with "support [of] conversion to short name equivalents" and a path that contains spaces or you have an issue with permissions. You need to discuss this with your admin.

Comment: it is a network drive (H:..) - abc until username is the name of the network drive. The name of the network drive never changed - so I think its not an issue of the name, but I could also not think about an issue in permission, as this also never had changed. I was already in contact with admins, but they do not know how the problem appeared.

Comment: Could just be the result of a silent windows update ... Who knows.

Comment: Thanks, I will try again to contact admins.